# setting up JBoss5 with MyEclipse

Tags: java, jboss, myeclipse

I have been using Weblogic as my company used it. Now I want to try JBoss as an alternative. I'm using Eclipse with MyEclipse 7.1 plugin. I downloaded and unzipped JBoss 5.0.1GA with Java JDK 1.5.0.14. I set the server up using MyEclipse interface and got the following error (couldn't find solution elsewhere online):

```
10:42:54,240 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Initializing recovery manager
10:42:54,300 FATAL [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.fail] RecoveryManagerImple: cannot bind to socket on address /127.0.0.1 and port 4,712
10:42:54,310 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Create: name=TransactionManager state=Configured
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.FatalError: Recovery manager already active (or recovery port and address are in use)!
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.RecoveryManagerImple.<init>(RecoveryManagerImple.java:146)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.RecoveryManager.<init>(RecoveryManager.java:372)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.RecoveryManager.manager(RecoveryManager.java:132)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.RecoveryManager.manager(RecoveryManager.java:113)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService.create(TransactionManagerService.java:207)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
```

.`............................`

Any ideas what is wrong in here?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is that the server is trying to use a port that is alredy in use.

Do you have any other web servers installed?  I know some have services that start up automatically.

To check for this on a windows box I usually reboot and the very first program I start up is the web server so it locks any ports it needs.

Comment: unfortunately, all sorts of things tend to grab ports that JBoss wants on Windows (in my case, in was usually some Intel network driver utilities.) TCPView can help identify/kill the guilty parties: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437 Alternatively, you can reconfigure the ports via the profile conf files, but I had difficulty getting Eclipse to recognise these changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case it was Skype that caused this problem. When I shutdown skype, the server starts ok again.

Answer (score 0):

**Close all java processing file from task manager and restart your IDE**

[image]